# Can I develop external Apps to a company with ABAP out of SAP software?

Tags: module, certificate, abap

I am a recent graduate in Systems Engineering (with a symbolic 2 years work experience in my area).

I'm loving the programming, development (web, mobile and desktop) applications.

I'm thinking of doing the certification SAP: ABAP. My question is: after obtaining the certification, Can I develop something more besides SAP Modules with the knowledge provided by the course and certification? I mean, Can I develop an App XY for an company C even if this one dont have any module like Basis, Bi, etc?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Unfortunately not.  ABAP is a proprietary language maintained by SAP, so it will only run within an SAP environment.  However, like all programming languages, the experience you get writing ABAP will still make you a better programmer if you decide to develop in something else (e.g. Java).

I would only get the certification if I knew for certain the costs would pay off. Where I live, it's very expensive, and most companies don't require it among their developers.

Comment: I have a working collegue, who gives nothing on certificates,he always says, Do You want to see my certificate? Look at my cv , 25 years of abap experience. What now ?